# How to efficiently replace a contiguous set of bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's say I have a binary number `1001100`, and I want to substitute it with `1011` at the section `[2, 6)`.

It would look something like this:

```
Binary: 1001100
Sub:    --1011-
Result: 1010110
```

I know it's possible to repeatedly set a single bit multiple times using this code:
`number |= 1UL << n;`

But I was wondering if there was a way to generally achieve this, in a more efficient way.

Comment: i feel like there isn't, and to make code neater you should just take that to (wrap it in) higher-level subroutines or functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets consider a more general problem: you have a binary number *a*, and you want to replace its bits by bits of another number *b*, only when the corresponding bit of third number *m* is one.

For your specific problem:

```
a = 1001100
b = xx1011x
m = 0011110
```

but there is no need to have *m* correspond to a single range.

A pseudo code to compute the result *r* would be

```
for all i in 0 to 6
  if m[i]=1
     r[i]=a[i]
  else
    r[i]=b[i]
```

or equivalently

```
for all i in 0 to 6
  r[i] = (a[i] and (m[i]=1)) or (b[i] and (m[i]=0))
```

We can easily deduce from this  that the loop is useless and that
the expression

```
r = (a & m) | (b & ~m)
```

gives the correct result.

Note that if you want to have a replacement on a specific range *k* to *l* (1 to 5 for instance in your case), the mask will be (2^l - 1) - (2^k - 1)  = 2^l - 2^k

So here is corresponding C code

```
unsigned int replace_bit(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, int k, int l){
  unsigned int mask=(1<<l) - (1<<k)
  return  (a & mask) | (b & ~mask) ;
}
```

Comment: The C version fails for bit-fields that go all the way to the top of the integer, since (`(1<<32) - (1<<0)` involves an out-of-bounds shift by 32, assuming 32-bit int.  If you used `(1ULL<<l) - (1ULL<<k)`, using 64-bit integers to create a 32-bit mask, you'd avoid that problem.  But might compile inefficiently on 32-bit machines.  (You should at least be using `1U<<l`, to avoid creating INT_MIN and then subtracting from it causing signed-overflow UB.  But that doesn't help with `l == 32`.)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way on the x86 architecture is by using the [PDEP instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) which intrinsic equivalent for 32-bit is

```
PDEP: unsigned __int32 _pdep_u32(unsigned __int32 src, unsigned __int32 mask);
```

The idea of its usage is

```
mov  ebx, 1001100b    ; initial value
mov  ecx, 0011110b    ; mask value (=SRC2) - bits to be replaced
mov  edx, 0001011b    ; bits to be inserted (=SRC1) at positions ECX
mov  eax, ecx         ; duplicate mask to EAX
not  eax              ; invert mask
and  ebx, eax         ; mask out bits that will be modified
pdep eax, edx, ecx    ; put bits from ECX to position specified by EDX into EAX
or   eax, ebx         ; merge masked initial value with result of PDEP
==>                   ; result is in EAX
```

This is the x86 assembly solution.
Transform it to an intrinsic representation if necessary.
Keep in mind that `PDEP` is kind of slow on AMD processors.
This solution works without any conditional operations like jumps.

Comment: If you have BMI2 `pdep`, you also have BMI1 [`andn`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn) to replace `mov`/`not`/`and`.  Also, you're just using `pdep` as a shift.  If your mask is a known constant, you could just `shl edx, 1` (or BMI2 `rorx eax, edx, 32-1` to copy-and-shift.)  `pdep` does also mask away high garbage in the input, so if you have fast `pdep` and throughput is more important than latency, it could be useful for that.